# image and matlab and DCT transform and jpeg

Tags: image, matlab, jpeg

I don't know much about matlab.
I have an image (in *png* format). How can I change the format to *jpeg*?
I need a command for it that does DCT of the image

thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to convert a *png* to *jpeg* you can do:

```
imwrite( imread( [imFilename, '.png'] ), [imFilename, '.jpg'] );
```